# How to create view in SQL procedure

Tags: sql, view, procedure

I'm trying to do something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AA_Hours_Union] 
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[aa_Hours]', 'V') IS NOT NULL 
         DROP VIEW [dbo].[aa_Hours];

    CREATE VIEW .....
```

but I get an error that create view must be the first line. So how do I create a view in a SQL procedure that will always drop the old one and create from scratch?

Comment: and why do you want to do these activities in the stored procedure?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The only possible reason I could think of for doing this would be if you were continually changing the definition of the view? If that's the case I would question whether your approach is correct.

Comment: i want to create view to connect it to my Model in Power BI 
maybe its really not best practice...

Answer (score 0):

It is a real pain, but you can do this using dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AA_Hours_Union] 
AS
BGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[aa_Hours]', 'V') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
         DROP VIEW [dbo].[aa_Hours];
    END;

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'CREATE VIEW .....';
END;
```